# Least Absolute Deviation in R

Tags: r

I have a LIST of dataframes. Each dataframe has the same numer of rows and columns.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
df
TIME  AMOUNT
20     456
30     345
15     122
12     267
```

Here is the expected `RESULT`:
I would like to count the `AMOUNT_NORM` column where

each value in the `AMOUNT` column was divided by the sum of all values in the `AMOUNT` column.

```
df
TIME  AMOUNT AMOUNT_NORM
20     456   0.38
30     345   0.29
15     122   0.1
12     267   0.22
```

Comment: Is `df$AMOUNT_NORM <- df$AMOUNT/sum(df$AMOUNT)` all you need?

Comment: that is right, but for the list of dataframes

Comment: Then you just want to apply that to each element of the list with `lapply`

Comment: Thanks but still not very helpful. The answer below gives the correct output but it would be great to have the answer for your type of solution. I have tried this but it doesn't work: 
    lapply (df, function (x) {
            x["AMOUNT_NORM"] <- NA
           x$AMOUNT_NORM <- x$AMOUNT/sum(x$AMOUNT)
          })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(AMOUNT_NORM = AMOUNT/SUM(AMOUNT))
```

EDIT: didn't read the list of dataframes bit. in this case you just do:

```
lapply(your_df_list, function(x) {
   x %>% mutate(AMOUNT_NORM = AMOUNT/SUM(AMOUNT))
})
```